# Create a schema in SQL Server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to read from a SQL Server database and create analogous copies of the same structure in a different database somewhere else.

Essentially:

```
  for db in source_dbs:
    Execute('create database [%s]' % db)  # THIS WORKS.
    for schema in db:
      # The following result in an error starting with:
      #   [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]

      Execute('create schema [%s].[%s]' % (db, schema)
      # Incorrect syntax near '.'

      Execute('use [%s]; create schema [%s]' %(db, schema)
      # CREATE SCHEMA' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

In this example, you can assume that `Execute` creates a cursor using `pyodbc` and executes the argument SQL string.

I'm able to create the empty databases, but I can't figure out how to create the schemas within them.

Is there a solution, or is this a limitation of using pyodbc with MS SQL Server?

*EDIT: FWIW - I also tried to pass the database name to Execute, so I could try to set the database name in the connection string.  This doesn't work either - it seems to ignore the database name completely.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python database connections usually default to having transactions enabled (`autocommit == False`) and SQL Server tends to dislike certain DDL commands being executed in a transaction.

I just tried the following and it worked for me:

```python
import pyodbc
connStr = (
    r"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};"
    r"Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;"
    r"Trusted_connection=yes;"
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("CREATE DATABASE pyodbctest")
crsr.execute("USE pyodbctest")
crsr.execute("CREATE SCHEMA myschema")
crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```